# Same scroll event to fire on multiple instances of element - vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, foreach, scroll, event-handling, requestanimationframe

I am trying to get 3 separate animations to move while I scroll down the page.
The behaviour is the same for all of them, so I have tried using forEach.

```
const svgContainer = document.querySelectorAll('.svg-container')
const textPath = document.querySelectorAll('.text-path')
const path = document.querySelectorAll('#wave');
const pathLength = path.getTotalLength();

const moveText = () => {
    requestAnimationFrame(function() {
        let scrollPercent;
        svgContainer.forEach(x => {
            scrollPercent = x.getBoundingClientRect().y / window.innerHeight;
        })
        textPath.forEach(x => {
            x.setAttribute('startOffset', scrollPercent * pathLength);
        })
    })
}
window.addEventListener('scroll', moveText);
```

However this doesn't work - see full code here: https://jsfiddle.net/chunzg/knr2y4ft/13/

(The 'Heading 1', 'Heading 2', and 'Heading 3' should move across horizontally from right to left of the screen as we scroll down, and move left to right as we scroll back up)

I then tried a different way, adding different class names to each instance, and grabbing all of them with querySelectorAll:

```
const svgContainer = document.querySelectorAll('.svg-container-1, .svg-container-2, .svg-container-3')
const textPath = document.querySelectorAll('.text-path-1, .text-path-2, .text-path-3')
const path = document.querySelectorAll('#wave-1, #wave-2, #wave-3');
const pathLength = path.getTotalLength();

const moveText = () => {
    requestAnimationFrame(function() { 
        var rect = svgContainer.getBoundingClientRect();
        var scrollPercent = rect.y / window.innerHeight;
        textPath.setAttribute('startOffset', scrollPercent * pathLength);
    })
}
window.addEventListener('scroll', moveText);
```

but doesn't work either: https://jsfiddle.net/chunzg/py0gox1n/16/

Where am I going wrong?

The only other way I can think of is to repeat the script for each heading separately but this wouldn't be dry code?

Comment: your first jsfiddle is querying `const svgContainer = document.querySelector('.svg-container')` instead of `querySelectorAll` and the same for `textPath` if I fix them both it works as expected for me.

Comment: Thank you, that did work - however, now that I've added more text to the paragraphs that separate the headings, only the last one works? The first two don't appear at all... new fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/chunzg/knr2y4ft/27/

Comment: You're using the same `window.innerHeight` for all of them, so as the window gets taller the effect becomes more extreme.

Comment: I changed it to `window.outerHeight` which works better but the main problem is still there. It looks like the last one is overriding the previous two, so that the previous two headings move at the same time as the last one, and go according to the last one's position... :/ https://jsfiddle.net/chunzg/knr2y4ft/39/ Do you think it will be too hard to solve?

Comment: `scrollPercent` ends up being whatever the last iteration of `svgContainer.forEach(..` set it to, so when you iterate `textPath` scrollPercent will always be that value. You need handle each textPath element individually inside the appropriate iteration of `svgContainer`

Comment: Thanks so much. I changed to this and it seems to work: 
https://jsfiddle.net/chunzg/knr2y4ft/54/
Although works better in my actual project compared to on the jsfiddle example for some reason.